# Is there a way to be notified when a view controller load a new view controller modally?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, notifications, modal-dialog, delegation

I need to be notified about modal view controller presentation, I know that I can do using `NSNotificationCenter` posting and observing my custom notifications, but I'd like to know if these kind of notification already exist.
Thanks,
 Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. I've just create an abstract class that overrides the methods for presenting a modal view, like that:

```
- (void) presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:PresentingModal object:self];
    [super presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated: animated];
}
```

Of course all my view controllers inherit from it.
Hope this helps.